# SSIS: cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types

Tags: ssis

I am working in SQL Server 2008 and BIDS (SSIS).  I have a simple data flow task in which I'm importing a flat file into an OLE DB destination.  On the OLE DB destination, I'm getting an error message, stating "cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types".

Now, I know one solution method is to put a data conversion in between the flat file and the OLE DB destination.  However, my concern is why this is even happening in the first place.  In the connection manager for the given flat file, all columns are string (DT_STR) data types, and the Unicode option is unchecked.  Similarly, all columns in the destination table (upon the inspection of the metadata in SSMS) are varchar data types.  So, there is no nvarchar-to-varchar mapping going on at all.

Why is SSIS thinking that I have a unicode-to-nonunicode mapping happening?  And, is there an easier way to resolve this than inserting a data conversion step for the columns that have this problem?

Comment: Use the Advanced Editor and check the input and output properties of your source and destination. If it shows different data types then there might be a problem with the metadata.

Answer (score 1):

[Since I don't seem to be allowed to comment on the question, I'm having to put my question here.]

Have you checked the table you're trying to insert the data into to see if the columns in the table are varchar or nvarchar? The SSIS metadata could be out of sync with the database table.